# Delegate or live or on in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, contextmenu

I use Context Menu for my project.
`ContextMenu` works perfectly. I dynamically insert a line on my table with ajax and suddenly, `contextMenu` does not work anymore.
How to use the delegate or live or on the function of jquery in my code?

```
$('#mytable').bootstrapTable({
contextMenu: '#context-menu',
onContextMenuItem: function (row, $el) {
    if ($el.data("item") == "add") {
    alert('It work');
    }

    if ($el.data("item") == "edit") {
    alert('It work');
    }
    if ($el.data("item") == "delete") {
    alert('It work');

    }
}
});
```

[ContextMenu](https://github.com/prograhammer/bootstrap-table-contextmenu)

Thanks,

Comment: What does "I dynamically insert a line on my table with ajax and suddenly, contextMenu does not work anymore" mean exactly? Not clear what the issue is here. What do you mean by line? What table? Why are you dynamically inserting lines? You need to provide more background/details. Also, I would advise against using the live() function as it is much slower than using on().

Comment: I insert a new line on my html table with ajax.

Comment: Where is the code that calls the ajax() function?